# Heroku app on node.js can't connect to heroku Postgre

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, heroku

I am writing a node.js app using Heroku and PostgreSQL. But when I try to make a request through Heroku it times out. Here are the Heroku logs:

```
2021-05-15T18:33:34.397049+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/login" host=aiposizi-test-api.herokuapp.com request_id=beb5b18d-9ecb-4730-b886-a5175c021377 fwd="37.214.57.227" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=53ms status=200 bytes=787 protocol=https
2021-05-15T18:34:10.015665+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/login" host=aiposizi-test-api.herokuapp.com request_id=f4e73df8-5116-426d-99a0-a2bfb08f3d16 fwd="37.214.57.227" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

My code for connection to DB and to execute a database query:

```
const {Pool} = require('pg');
const pool = new Pool({
    connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    ssl: {
        required: true,
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
});

pool.query(`SELECT * FROM Users;`, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error - Failed to select all from Users');
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        console.log(res.rows);
    }
});
```

The process looks like an endless database connection. It connects to the Heroku Postgre via `psql` without any problems. `proccess.env.DATABASE_URL` contents URI for connetcion. I have already tried all possible connection methods - the problem has not been solved.

Comment: Can you check whether there's an environment variable with the name of `DATABASE_URL` ? Just in case.

Comment: Yes, there is. Also, if I write console.log to output this variable, it outputs URI for connection.

Comment: Interesting.. Have you tried removing SSL configuration?